# PHP + Mysql : How to insert data having , " ' (Semicolon, Single + Double Quotation Marks)

Tags: php, mysql

Sometimes it sucks when you have these ; " ' (semicolon, single and double quotation marks) everything in a string.

Question is simple what is the easiest way to send those sting into the database.

```
base64_encode();
base64_decode();
// Is not an option. I need to keep those data just same as it is.
```

Comment: Use something like PDO and bind variables.

Comment: use escape string before insert into database...

Comment: You can use `addslashes()` to handle  single and double quotation marks for inserting into the DB.

Comment: Use prepared statements with either PDO or mysqli functions. They will not only properly escape special characters, but help prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PDO statements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) is the best solution to your problem of executing SQL queries to your database with values that have single/double quotation marks... but **more importantly** PDO statements help **prevent SQL injection**.

To show you how this works, this very simple example gives you a basic understanding of how PDO statements work. All this example does is make the connection to the database and insert the username, email and password to the users table.

```
<?php
// START ESTABLISHING CONNECTION...
 $dsn = 'mysql:host=host_name_here;dbname=db_name_here';
 //DB username
 $uname = 'username_here';
 //DB password
 $pass = 'password_here';

 try
     {

     $db = new PDO($dsn, $uname, $pass);

     $db->setAttribute(PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES);
     error_reporting(0);
     } catch (PDOException $ex)
     {
     echo "Database error:" . $ex->getMessage();
     }

// END ESTABLISHING CONNECTION - CONNECTION IS MADE.


 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $hashed_password = password_hash($password, DEFAULT_BCRYPT);

 //Validation on inputs here...

 // Your SQL query... here is a sample one.
 $query = "INSERT INTO users (userName, email, password) VALUES (:userName, :email, :password)";

 $statement = $db->prepare($query);
 // The values you wish to put in.
 $statementInputs = array("userName" => $username, "email" => $email, "password" => $hashed_password);

 $statement->execute($statementInputs);
 $statement->closeCursor();
?>
```

You could put the establishing connection part in a separate file and require_once that file to avoid having to write the same code, again and again  to establish a connection to your database.

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
addslashes('your text') // in your php page
```

Answer (score 1):

Use mysqli_real_escape_string

```
$someText = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,"It's a test.");
```

where $con is your database connection variable.